# How to create sub menuitem in intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

I have create a Menu item under the Main menu however I want to create a submenu item like this image [image]

I have used this xml tag in the plugin.xml for menu. I want to create a submenuitem like the red marking on the image.

```xml
<actions>
    <!-- Add your actions here -->
    <group id="MyPlugin.test" text="_" description="test">
        <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"  />
        <!--<action id="Myplugin.Textboxes" class="Mypackage.TextBoxes" text="Text _Boxes" description="A  menu item" />
        <action id="Myplugin.Dialogs" class="Mypackage.MyShowDialog" text="Show _Dialog" description="A  menu item" />-->
        <action id="testAndroidPlugin.MyAction" class="com.test.bijesh.MyActionClass" text="Create String"
                description="The action implemented by MyActionClass class">
            <!--<add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="after" relative-to-action="WindowMenu"/>-->
            <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="ctrl alt S"/>
        </action>
        <action id="testAndroidPlugin.ManageResources" class="com.test.bijesh.actions.ColorActions" text="Create Color"
                description="The action implemented by ColorAction class">
            <!--<add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="after" relative-to-action="WindowMenu"/>-->
            <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="ctrl alt C"/>
        </action>
    </group>
</actions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we do it in [Ceylon IDE](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-ide-intellij/blob/e4c7bffc8d2bb458835aa71244b39cbf80c62cb6/META-INF/plugin.xml#L45-L57):

```xml
<actions>
    <group text="Ceylon" icon="/icons/ceylon.png" popup="true">
        <action> ...</action>
        <add-to-group group-id="ToolsMenu" anchor="last"/>
    </group>
</actions>
```

This results in `Tools > Ceylon > ...`. I think your version does not work because `text="_"` generates an empty text (`_` is used for keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: This approach doesn't work for the "GenerateGroup" menu.

Answer (score 0):

A nested action:

```
<actions>
    <group id="YourCompany.All" popup="true" class="com.company.CompanyActionGroup">
        <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="before" relative-to-action="HelpMenu"/>
    </group>
    <group id="YourCompany.All.Foo" popup="true" class="com.company.FooActionGroup">
        <add-to-group group-id="YourCompany.All" anchor="first"/>
        <action
            id="some.action"
            text="Do Action"
            description="This will do the action."
            class="com.yourcompany.FooAction"
            icon="/icons/foo.svg"
        />
    </group>
</actions>
```

This gives

Menu: A > B > Do Action

(Where the text for A & B are defined in the `class`'s referenced).