# nested menu group in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create a intellij plugin, which will be under Tools menu and itself is a group of actions. I followed the example given here

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/action_system/grouping_action.html

but i am not able to get a grouped action, the action appears under the tools menu but its not a grouped action

[image]

Its something like

Tools -> Custom Grouped Action

however i want

Tools -> DefaultActionGroup Inheritor -> Custom Grouped Action

Below is code from actions

```
<actions>
        <!-- Add your actions here -->
        <group id="CustomDefaultActionGroup"
               text="DefaultActionGroup Inheritor" description="Default Action Group Demo">
            <add-to-group group-id="ToolsMenu" anchor="last"/>
            <action class="RME" id="CustomGroupedAction"
                    text="Custom Grouped Action" description="Custom Grouped Action Demo"/>
        </group>
    </actions>
```

Comment: Is there an Action class to match "CustomGroupedAction" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create sub menuitem in intellij plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833903/how-to-create-sub-menuitem-in-intellij-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `popup="true"` attribute to `<group>` tag, as in the example you mentioned.